# How to copy certain urls from a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard

I have hundreds of page which I need to grab the urls of certain filehosters, but since the number of link for each page and the pages theyself, it has been tested to find the string and copy to the clipboard , using javascript

```
static getFileUrl(id){
    var url=new URL("https://fileshosting.net/file/FileUrl")
    url.searchParams.append('*',id)
    return url.href
}
static copyFileUrl(id){
    copy(this.getFileUrl(id))

}
```

I'm not to used to javascript but this should suffice, and everything it gets its the next console output

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier
```

I understand this mean a semicolon before the statement is missing. But I don't get where it is. AFAIK there are two statement (the static procedures).
And sometimes there is only one url but in other pages there are 20  or 50 urls so perhaps it should be used an array, but I don't know how to implement an array in javascript.

so is there some method to, instead of open manually page to page, parse it from a terminal and pipe it to this (java)script or another language rutine?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
I have found another way, since it doesn't work this approach.
Thanks for the support and time.

Comment: `I understand this mean a semicolon before the statement is missing` not always - which line throws the `Uncaught SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier`? Note: `static` is not valid outside of a `class` definition, so, that's probably an issue

Comment: if you're worried about `;` ... you could throw one at the end of every line in your code between `{` and `}` - but it won't fix the issue if you're using `static` wrong

Comment: I'm pretty certain the problem isn't in the code you shared. Also, are you sure you copy-pasted the error exactly? I think the only type of that thing I've seen is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. Or maybe an evil text editor inserted an evil zero width space or something like that. Try typing out the code again, manually, not copy-pasting.

Comment: @code - firefox produces `"SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier"` Chrome/EdgeChrome produces `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"` perhaps some other browser produces a combination of the two :p

Comment: either way, as shown, it's not valid - since `static` is only valid inside a `class`

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's the NEXT line after this code that is the issue - a further guess is, that the next "token" is `function`

Comment: Thanks for the support, give me a litte time to study the ideas